# Please the Inequality in the proof of The Isoperimetric Inequality

Tags: differential-geometry, inequality

From [A proof of the Isoperimetric Inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19997/a-proof-of-the-isoperimetric-inequality-how-does-it-work), can you please explain the starred inequality $$A + \pi r^2 = \int_{\gamma} x\,dy + \int_C -y\,dx = \int^l_0 x(s)y_s(s)\,ds - \int^l_0 \overline{y}(s)x_s(s)\,ds = $$

$$ = \int^l_0 ( x(s)y_s(s) - \overline{y}(s)x_s(s)) \,ds \le \int^l_0 \sqrt{ (x(s)y_s(s) - \overline{y}(s)x_s(s))^2} \,ds \stackrel{*}{\le}$$

$$ \stackrel{*}{\le} \int^l_0 \sqrt{ (x^2(s) + \overline{y}^2(s))} \,ds = lr$$

Where the starred inequality follows from the fact that:

$$(x y_s - \overline{y} x_s)^2 = [(x, - \overline{y}) \cdot (y_s, x_s)]^2 \le (x^2 + \overline{y}^2) \cdot (y^2_s + x^2_s) = x^2 + \overline{y}^2 $$

This is my question: How do you justify this inequality?
$$(x y_s - \overline{y} x_s)^2 \le (x^2 + \overline{y}^2) \cdot (y^2_s + x^2_s)$$

If you expand the left and right hand side you get
$$ x^2 y_s^2 -2xx_s \overline{y}y_s + \overline{y}^2 x_s^2 \le x^2y_s^2 +x^2 x_s^2 + \overline{y}^2 y_s^2 +\overline{y}^2 x_s^2 $$

So why is 
$$ -2xx_s \overline{y}y_s \le x^2 x_s^2 + \overline{y}^2 y_s^2 $$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cauchy inequality for inner products? And your last inequality follows from the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. Expand $(xx_s + \bar yy_s)^2$.