# Arc length parametrization of piecewise $C^1$-curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, parametrization

How do we known that an arc-length parametrization of a piecewise $C^1$-curve exists? I know that if a curve is regular (i.e. its velocity vectors are non-zero), then such a parametrization exists. But otherwise?

I asked this question since this is used in the proof of the isoperimetric inequality:

> If $C$ is a simple closed piecewise $C^1$ curve of length $\ell$, with its interior having area $A$, then $\ell^2-4\pi A \geq 0$. Furthermore, equality holds if and only if $C$ is a circle.

A proof of isoperimetric inequality as presented in do Carmo's book "Differenatial Geometry of Curves and Sufaces" requires choosing an arc-length parametrization for the simple closed curve under consideration. (See also here: [A proof of the Isoperimetric Inequality - how does it work?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19997/a-proof-of-the-isoperimetric-inequality-how-does-it-work) for the proof I have in mind, although the arc-length parametrization is needed for the part which says that an equality holds if and only if the curve is a circle, which is not discussed in the linked post.)

Comment: How are you defining a $C^1$ curve? (Locally) as the vanishing locus of a $C^1$ function $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$? If so, then you can apply the implicit function theorem to get a parametrisation (locally).